# 3D effect like "safari new tab page" on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, 3d

I would like to develop an iPhone/iPad 3d interface like the "Safari browser new tab page" ( a screenshot [here](http://images.marketingtechblog.com/uploads/2009/06/safari-new-tab.png) ).

The tricky part is to display the images in a non rectangular zone. As you can see, the images are displayed in a curved zone.
Hence my question, what is the easiest way to do it ?

I am thinking about doing it with OpenGL. In this case each picture would be a texture that is  applied in a 3d discretized curve. Do you think that can fill the bill ?

What's more, I'am asking if there is not a tip to do it only with 2D rendering... that could be easiest to implement.

If anyone has a comment or an idea, you're welcome ;)